# Use .title() method without converting to lowercase

Tags: python, string, methods

this is a very simple problem, I need to convert for example the string `luis XIV de francia` into `Luis XIV De Francia` in Python. However, if I use the `.title()` method like this:

```
'luis XIV de francia'.title()
```

The result is `Luis Xiv De Francia`. I don't want `XIV` to turn into `Xiv`.

So the question is: Is there something like `.title()` but that does not transform the other characters (those that are not the first letter of the word) to lowercase?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you could simply make a lambda function to only upper the First one to fit you need. Like:
" ".join(map(lambda x:x[0].upper()+x[1:], 'luis XIV de francia'.split(' ')))

Comment: Hi, I thought maybe there was a solution that didn't need to create a custom function, but this seems to work, thanks a lot!

Comment: What should be the result for `luis XIV de frANCIA` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  `regular expressions` to find the first letter of any word and `upper()` it:

```
import re
def custom_title(s):
    return re.sub(r"(?:(?<=\W)|^)\w(?=\w)", lambda x: x.group(0).upper(), s)

custom_title('luis XIV de francia')
# > 'Luis XIV De Francia'
```

The `regex's sub` method makes it suitable with larger strings with punctation.

```
custom_title('luis XIV de francia, something. foo-bar')
# > 'Luis XIV De Francia, Something. Foo-Bar'
```

Here's another version to also capitalize **single letter words**:

```
def custom_title(s):
    return re.sub(r"(?:(?<=\W)|^)\w", lambda x: x.group(0).upper(), s)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `title()` method doesn't know that 'xiv' is a roman numeral. The best you can do is segment your string, then `title()` the relevant pieces, and leave the XIV part as is, then concatenate the pieces together. I think a program will not realize a group of characters might be a roman numeral.

```
def title_except_all_caps(input):
    parts = [p.title() if p.islower() else p for p in input.split()]
    return ' '.join(parts)
```

Although the explanation talked about roman numerals, I want you to understand what is going on here. This splits the original string between whitespace, then if it is a lowercase string, apply `title()` to it. If not, leave it alone. Finally, assemble the resulting string by concatenating the parts using a space as the joiner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I don't need the program to recognize roman numerals, I need something that for example turns "foo foo BAR" into "Foo Foo BAR" and not into "Foo Foo Bar".

Comment: What my code does is leave all-caps segments alone. It has nothing to do with roman numerals.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but it would not work with "foo foo bAr".

Comment: No, it would not -- but because 'bAr' is not all caps, it will become Bar. In your original question statement, you weren't clear about why XIV was special, so I had initially assumed it was roman numerals, but then figured it SHOULD be in all caps if you wanted it to stay all caps. That is the solution I provided.

Comment: Said another way, if your criteria for making it title case was if it was all lowercase, then simply replace the `not p.isupper()`` with `p.islower()` and that might be more what you were thinking. You _did_ try the example code, right?

Comment: I wanted to convert something like 'CalCuluS II' to 'Calculus II'. `not p.isupper()` was better in this case.

Comment: I guess in the end, more examples would have helped clarify what to use as the "title-ify" condition. Yes, if we knew we'd have upper case characters mixed in, then your condition would have worked.